# Saving map of structures

Tags: c++

How i can save map of structure in c++ to txt?
I have that code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct category {
        int id;
        std::string name;
};

map<int, category> categories;

int main() {
        category tmp1 = { 1, "First category" };
        category tmp2 = { 2, "Second category" };

        categories[1] = tmp1;
        categories[2] = tmp2;
        fstream file;
        file.open("test.txt", ios::out, ios::app);
        file << categories[1] << endl << categories[2];
        file.close();
}
```

I have error in vscode but i cant read it.

Comment: you cannot read the error message? Why not?

Comment: Instead of creating a bunch of junk variables and then force-assigning into a `std::map`, why not just [provide that data to the constructor direcrtly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) or at the least [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) them?

Comment: i dont understand it

Comment: it is so long and i just dont know what is in it

Comment: i suggest you to forget about the map for a moment, because the map isnt the problem. C++ does not provide an automagic way to print custom types to a file (or stdout, or anywhere). How you can do it is explained in the duplicate

Comment: where is duplicate (sry im new)